# Find Motorola BLE API

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola

Please I'm searching Motorola Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) API And SDK. The links founds on Motorola web site are now available. If somebody has got it and he can send a link where I can get it, It will be wonderful. I'm working on Motorola watch MotoAct. Please I need a help. below that links are not available :

http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html
http://developer.motorola.com/tools/resources/

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can build the plug-ins yourself, as they are now open source. my understanding is the BLE API is factored in... the instructions can be found here: http://www-uat.motorola.com/sites/motodev/library/motodev_core_plugins.html however, I've been battling through this, i have some 33 errors I cant resolve. Additionally, I had to get the sequoyah plugins from here (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/eclipse/sequoyah/updates/2.1/2.1.1.N20120718-0509/) and source those as a local file. im not quite sure what I'm missing, but maybe this can get you going. If anyone else figures out how to complete the ins

Answer (score 0):

if your Motorola device is an Android device and supports BLE according with the Bluetooth.org supported devices list, you should be able to program anything with the Android API. regards